# How to attain this hover effect in css where I can form a dot and a longer line on hover

Tags: html, css, navbar

I want this dot and a longer dot effect:

[image]

I tried the linear gradient but could not get the rounded edges.

The code I tried looked like this:

```
padding-block-end: 0.4rem;
border-block-end: 0.3rem solid;
border-image-source: linear-gradient(to right,
        rgb(255, 255, 255) 0% 30%,
        rgb(206, 21, 181) 33% 40%,
        rgb(255, 255, 255) 43% 45%,
        rgb(219, 17, 192) 48% 70%,
        rgb(255, 255, 255) 73% 100%);
border-image-slice: 10% 20%;
border-radius: 10px;
```

But I got this:

[image]

Comment: share your code in a snippet then support it with images if necessary. don't just post images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out and then just copy what you need:

```css
.outer {
  width: 130px;
  height: 130px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  border-radius: 8px;
  text-align: center;
}

body {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.div1,
.div2 {
  background-color: red;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  margin: 2px;
}

.div1 {
  width: 20%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.div2 {
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <h1>Hello</h1>
  <div class="div1"></div>
  <div class="div2"></div>
</div>
```